# Mapping object to child component in React

Tags: json, reactjs

Using React I am trying to pass down a parsed JSON file and map through the object. However seeing as it is an object I can only map the object using Object.keys as below:

```
const question = Object.keys(questions).map((data, index) =>
    <QuestionList questions={data} key={index} />
```

However using this I am only able to access the top level of my data structure. So using this code and passing down my object. Using Object.keys() I can only access "questions" or "q1" or type, text, qId etc. I can not pass all object properties at once and specify what I need in a child component.

```
"questions": {
    "q1": {
      "qId": "1",
      "type": "YN",
      "text": "Text 1",
      "tip": {
        "logo": "assets/icons/gadgetz.svg",
        "logofallback": "assets/img/gadgetz.png",
        "heading": "Heading 1",
        "text": "Text 2"
      }
    },...
```

What would be the easiest way to pass the whole object with child properties so I can use these in a child component? do I have to use something other than props?

Comment: Why can't you pass the entire object?

Comment: Yes, you can pass an object as a Prop Types. I think the issue is that you are passing values that are paths to images, that might be an issue if you're using webpack.

Comment: Maybe the error is elsewhere seeing as you are stating that this should work.

The reason I think this does not work is because this code:

`{JSON.stringify(this.props.questions)}`

returns only the key "questions", "q1, q2, q3", or "qId, type, text" depending on how I pass down the object.

If I write `{JSON.stringify(this.props.questions.q1)}` the object is empty.

Comment: Are you trying to make a child component for each top-level key - ie q1, q2, q3, etc.? Need some clarity on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to use the same component to render q1, q2, q3. However I can't access all properties of the "q1" object because my iteration returns only the keys of the object "level" I am mapping. Furthermore if I pass down `this.props.questions.q1` I receive only the keys and no values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const questionObjects = Object.values(JSON.stringify(theJSONinYourQuestion));

const questionComponents = questionObjects.map(question => <Question qId={question.qId} />);
```

Basically, use `Object.values` instead of `Object.keys`, and you've got a nice array of questions you can use.

**Edit**: if you don't have `Object.values` available in your environment [(it is experimental)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```
const originalQuestions = JSON.stringify(theJSONinYourQuestion);
const questionKeys = Object.keys(orginalQuestions);
const questionObjects = questionKeys.map(key => originalQuestions[key]);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain access to the question object inside of a .map by assigning it to a variable outside that scope. [Here's a jsBin](https://jsbin.com/suzitoqiro/edit?html,js,console,output) showing the idea

```
const objectOfQuestions = {
    "questions": {
        "q1": {
            "qId": "1",
            "type": "YN",
            "text": "Text 1",
            "tip": {
                "logo": "assets/icons/gadgetz.svg",
                "logofallback": "assets/img/gadgetz.png",
                "heading": "Heading 1",
                "text": "Text 2"
            }
        },
         "q2": {
            "qId": "2",
            "type": "YN",
            "text": "Text 1",
            "tip": {
                "logo": "assets/icons/gadgetz.svg",
                "logofallback": "assets/img/gadgetz.png",
                "heading": "Heading 1",
                "text": "Text 2"
            }
        }
    }
}

const Question = ({ id, question }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Question: {id}</h1>
      <p>id: {question.qId}</p>
      <p>type: {question.type}</p>
      <p>text: {question.type}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const QuestionList = ({ questions }) => {
  const questionObj = questions;
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(questions.questions).map((key, i) => {
         return (
           <div key={key}>
             <Question id={key} question={questionObj.questions[key]} />
           </div>
          );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<QuestionList questions={objectOfQuestions} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```